# How to force update syncs on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm making changes on a Google Storage bucket, e.g. setting some CORS settings ([See gsutil example here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin)) or updating a file through the web interface.

Executing the same CURL command 50 times I got the old settings 44 times, the new settings only 6 times.

Ok, it's cloud, it's distributed, hopefully it will update sooner or later. But during development it's a pain in some very unconvenient areas... How can I force Google Storage to spread the changes in all of their servers asap?

Comment: Are they public objects? The default cache control is 1 hour, see [Cache-Control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#cachecontrol) and [cache control consistency](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency#cache-control).